# Dropdown value and radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm actually trying to bind my dropdown and my radio button which is has to be checked when one of the dropdown values is selected and if nothing is selected it is unchecked.

So actually my code isn't going to my "else if" part and I don't know why...

Thanks for helping.

Here is my code for that section :

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <ul id="operation">
                        <li class="operationList">Versement</li>
                        <li class="operationList">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btnDropDown myBtn" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Rachat <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="font-weight: bold; color: black">Rachat</h6>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item rachat">Rachat partiel</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item rachat">Rachat partiel programme</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item rachat">Rachat total</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="operationList">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btnDropDown myBtn" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Arbitrage
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="font-weight: bold; color: black">Arbitrage</h6>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item arbitrage">Arbitrage fonds</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item arbitrage">Arbitrage modes de gestion</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item arbitrage">Arbitrage orientation de gestion</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="ulOperationListBtn">
                        <li class="operationListBtn"><input class="radio1" type="radio" name="operation" value="versement" /></li>
                        <li class="operationListBtn"><input class="radio2" type="radio" name="operation" value="rachat" /></li>
                        <li class="operationListBtn"><input class="radio3" type="radio" name="operation" value="arbitrage"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            var htmlText = text;
            var rachat = $('.rachat');
            var arbitrage = $('.arbitrage');

            if (rachat) {
                console.log(arbitrage);
                console.log($('.radio2'));
                $('.radio2').attr('checked', 'checked');
            } else if (arbitrage) {
                console.log("hereWeGo");
                $('.radio3').attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            else{
                $('.radio2').attr('unchecked', 'unchecked');
                $('.radio3').attr('unchecked', 'unchecked');
            }

            $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(htmlText);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try using `.length` instead of `!= null`.. My guess is its never null, as its a JQuery object with just a lengh of 0.

Comment: But the "if" part is working?

Comment: Actually sorry I was doing juste a "if (rachat) else if (arbitrage)" nothing else and only the "if" part was working. my radio button linked to "radio2" class was checked.

I'm changing my code for it sorry,

so if I change my code and doing if (rachat.length){....} it's only doing the same as i said it's checking me second radio button and never the third one

Comment: Even with those changes, the selectors will still remain truthy. try using `.length`.. i.e. `if(rachat.length)` - console.log those before the if statement, and use .length

Comment: @JFit When I'm trying it with .length, it's still not going on the second else if.

Comment: Like JFit said, try a console.log before the "if" to see the value of the variables

Comment: So i did the console.log before the if sentence, and nothing appear to the console. But when i selected one of my dropdown choice it's printing 3.

Comment: @Kira for which variable? rachat or arbitrage?

Comment: Okay guys, my bad if I put the console logs for rachat or arbitrage it's screening me 3. 
I was putting the console.log in the same function but that was waiting the "click" event... sorry for that